# Почему Г.Шилдт пишет, что generator-объекты сразу удаляются?

Tags: java, объекты, сборщик-мусора

Можете объяснить, почему пишут, что `generator-объекты` сразу удаляются, разве не должны они дождаться сборщика мусора?
Я представляю себе работу программы примерно так: в `for`е внутри `ob` создются
одноимённые `'o'`-обекты с разными значениями:
вызывая `void generator(i)`, создаются объекты: `о=new FDemo(1)=1`,
`о=new FDemo(2)=2,o=3,o=4....`.
Так как метод `void`,то каждый созданный(пусть и одноимённый) объект "превращается" просто в отдельную ячейку памяти (к которой нельзя обратиться), содержащую какое-то значение.

```
class FDemo {
    int х;
    FDemo(int i) {
        х = i;
    }
    // Вызывается при удалении объекта
    protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("Финaлизaция " + х);
    }

    // Генерирует объект, который тотчас же уничтожается <-----От сборки мусора(но тогда не тотчас уничтожится) или как?
    void generator(int i) {
        FDemo о = new FDemo( i );
    }
}

class Finalize {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int count;
        FDemo оb = new FDemo(O);
        /* Генерируется большое количество объектов.
        В какой-то момент должна начаться сборка мусора*/
        for(count=1; count < 100000; count++)
            ob.generator(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут уже все зависит от целого ряда параметров (таких как: на какой jre запущена программа, каким javac была скомпилирована, с какими ключами... (спасибо нестандартизированным возможностям оптимизации)). Но, по стандарту, объекты создаются в хипе. Т.к. объект локальный, метод сразу заканчивает выполнение, то, фактически, ссылок на данный объект нет и GC МОЖЕТ (но не обязан) его удалять. Однако, иногда есть ньюансы (о которых я писал выше).

Comment: Допустим у нас в форе 512 шаг и сборки пока не было,можем ли мы называть прошлые 511 одноимённых,void 'o'-объектов(содержащих какие-то числа)объектами или это уже что-то другое?

Comment: Если-да,то получается куча одноимённых объектов(пусть и нессылаемых) имеет одинаковое имя но разные значения,но как такое возможно:почему все они не имеют значение последнего объекта?

Comment: @Alabushka а вот тут уже пошло непонимание. 1. void обозначает, что метод не возвращает значение. Объектов этого типа не существует. 2. В вашем случае, у всех объектов тип FDemo. 3. Имена переменных будут храниться на стеке, который, как раз будет удален сразу, по выходу из метода. В хипе есть только адрес памяти, но никак не имя, а вот на стеке храниться информация, которую можно интерпретировать как «переменная о (на самом деле, имя переменной может быть изменено во время компиляции) ссылается на участок памяти 0х234..., в которой храниться объект типа ... .FDemo»

Comment: 1."У всех объектов будет тип FDemo"-имеется ввиду на момент их создания или в долгосрочной переспективе( уже не в ОП)?2.Стек сразу удаляется сборщиком или при помощи какого-то особого механизма? 3.Почему назван участок памяти 0х234(он произволен?)

Comment: @Alabushka 1. Объект не может изменить свой тип. Т.е., если вы создали объект определенного класса - он таким будет всегда. 2. Нет. Стек удаляется не сборщиком. В данном случае речь о стеке вызовов, который управляется самой операционной системой. 3. Да, каждому объекту в хипе выделяется некий произвольный участок памяти